# Checking if the referer is empty or if it is in an array

Tags: php, if-statement, symfony1, logic

I am trying to write an if statement that basically checks if the users referrer is in a list of allowed referrers and if not fails.

I have two variables controlling this `$this->allowAllReferer` and `$this->allowEmptyReferer`, which as per their name decide whether every referrer should be allowed access and whether empty referrers are allowed, respectively. As well as `$this->allowedReferers` which is an array of allowed referrers.

I have this function below which I am pretty sure isn't working properly but I have been staring at and tweaking it for half an hour and i've got to the point where I can't tell if it's working or not.

```
//If the referee is empty and allow empty referrer is false
//or
//If it is not in the allowed list and allow all referer is false 
if(!(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $this->allowEmptyReferer)
    &&
   !(!$this->allowAllReferer && in_array(
      strtolower(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? null : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), //Silly php access null variable
      $this->allowedReferers)
    )) {
    throw new sfException("Internal server error. Please contact system administrator. File download disabled.");
}
```

Do you know the correct or a better way to do this/can you confirm the above works?

---

Cases, hope this makes it more clear

```
empty_referrer | allowEmpty | in_array | allReferer | result
----------------------------------------------------------------
true           | true       | false    | false      | false - no error - empty allowed
false          | true       | false    | false      | true - error - not in array
false          | true       | false    | true       | false - no error - not in array but allowed
false          | false      | false    | false      | true - error - empty and now allowed
```

Comment: your truth-table is incomplete ;) it would need 16 (2^4) lines ^^

Comment: ha! yep I know, just lost interest after four and thought I would have got the idea across by then xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to keep the logic within one huge if block, then try the following:

```
if (
    // throw an error if it's empty and it's not allowed to be
    (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !$this->allowEmptyReferer)
    || (
      // don't bother throwing an error if all are allowed or empty is allowed
      (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !$this->allowAllReferer)
      // throw an error if it's not in the array
      && !in_array((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? null : strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])), $this->allowedReferers)
    )
)
{
  throw new sfException("Internal server error. Please contact system administrator. File download disabled.");
}
```

The second check for empty will now skip the in_array if it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$ref = &$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($allowAll) {
  // allowed
} else if($allowEmpty && empty($ref)) {
  // allowed
} else if(!empty($ref) && in_array($ref, $allowedReferers)) {
  // allowed
} else {
  // fail
}
```

If you want to have all checks in a single `if`, you can simply chain together the conditions using `or`/`||`. Short-circuit evaluation ensures proper variable values and immediate termination of the condition check:

```
$ref = &$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($allowAll
    || ($allowEmpty && empty($ref))
    || (!empty($ref) && in_array($ref, $allowedReferers))) {
  // allowed
} else {
  // fail
}
```

Comment: I would much prefer to do it in one statement, more for the challenge than anything but thanks for the post.

Comment: @pez: simply use `||` instead of `else if`. short-circuit magic does the rest

Comment: What happens here if it is empty but not allowed to be, 2nd row fails so third row is checked with an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, then this is most in keeping with your original code

```
        if( (!$this->allowEmptyReferer && empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
           || (!$this->allowAllReferer && !in_array(
          strtolower(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? null : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),
          $this->allowedReferers)
        ) { // throw your exception }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your logic, something like this:

```
if (!$this->allowAllReferer)
{
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !$this->allowEmptyReferer)
    {
        // emtpy referer - not allowed. handle as you wish (throw exception?)
    }

    else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) &&
        !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])), $this->allowedReferers)
    {
        // referer supplied is not approved/allowed. - handle appropriately.
    }

    else
    {
        // referer should be ok if we get here.
    }   

}
```

ie. First of all if you are allowing all referers, then you don't need to do any processing - just skip this (`if (!this->allowAllReferer)`).
Second, break up your logic checks into management chunks it makes it easier to write, read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```